# Roblox Studio Lua's I'm having trouble with "Infinite yield possible"

Tags: lua, roblox

Whenever I try to correct the error it continues
What could it be?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: why do you share text as an image? that doesn't make sense

Comment: Please always include any textual content (code, error message, ...) as `formatted` text in your question description. Image content cannot be searched. For more details see [You should not post code as an image because](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5698098).

Comment: Also as a new contributor, _Welcome to Stack Overflow_. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

From the Roblox manual:

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/WaitForChild

> - If a call to this function exceeds 5 seconds without returning, and
>   no timeOut parameter has been specified, a warning will be printed to
>   the output that the thread may yield indefinitely; this warning takes
>   the form Infinite yield possible on 'X:WaitForChild("Y")', where X is
>   the parent name and Y is the child object name.
> - This function does not yield if a child with the given name exists    when the call is made.

Answer (score 0):

As Piglet had said, read the reference for WaitForChild;

the problem your having is that QuestGive is not added yet inside of serverstorage, this means that the script will wait until it finds QuestGive in server storage. Make sure that QuestGive **ENTERS** server storage or **EXISTS**!

Answer (score 0):

The client cannot see instances created by the server inside of ServerStorage and the same for ServerScriptService. Both of these are meant for storing server-side objects and logic respectively and are not replicated to connected clients.

Answer (score -1):

it means that QuestGive does not exist or you made a typo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).